# Translation of "audio signalling"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

How do I translate "audio signalling of each detected particle"

I was trying:

> Señalización de audio para cada particula detectada

or

> Señalamiento con audio para cada particula detectada

is it correct or is there a better translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one looks right to me. An alternative could be:

> Señalización auditiva de cada partícula detectada.

Or also "Señalización sonora" - less literal but more natural.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for the first option you present:

> Señalización de audio para cada particula detectada

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué tal "la señal sonora de cada partícula detectada"?